# How can I make a Haskell parser from a list of words?

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec

I'm a Haskell beginner, using Attoparsec to find some color expressions in a text. I want to be able to match, for example, "light blue-green" and "light blue green" in a text. But of course I need a generalized solution for any string like that. So I've been thinking that it would be something like

```
"light" >> sep >> "blue" >> sep >> "green"
  where sep = inClass "\n\r- "
```

In other words, I think I need a way to intercalate `>> sep >>` to a list of words. Something like:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Attoparsec.Text

-- | Makes a parser from a list of words, accepting
-- spaces, newlines, and hyphens as separators.
wordListParser :: [T.Text] -> Parser
wordListParser wordList = -- Some magic here
```

Or maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way entirely, and there's an easier way?

Edit: this minimal non-working example feels like it's almost there:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Replace.Attoparsec.Text
import Data.Attoparsec.Text as AT
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Control.Applicative (empty)

wordListParser :: [T.Text] -> Parser T.Text
wordListParser (w:ws) = string w >> satisfy (inClass " -") >> wordListParser ws
wordListParser [w] = string w
wordListParser [] = empty  -- or whatever the empty parser is

main :: IO ()
main = parseTest (wordListParser (T.words "light green blue")) "light green-blue"
```

which I think can be run with something like

```
stack runhaskell ThisFile.hs --package attoparsec replace-attoparsec text
```

Comment: What do you want the result of parsing `light blue-green` to be?

Comment: You probably want to use `sepBy1` and `choice`.

Comment: The result should be T.Text. How would I use `sepBy1`?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the edit in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do, assuming that you have a data type for your colours; if you don't, just substitute it for what you're using. The function `parseColourGen` takes any `Text` that is space-separated, and generates a parser that accepts a colour where each word is separated by one or more legal separators.

```
import Prelude hiding (concat, words)
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))
import Data.Attoparsec.Text
import Data.List (intersperse)
import Data.Text (concat, pack, singleton, Text,  words)

data Colour = LightBlue | DarkBlue | VibrantRed deriving Show

parseColourGen :: Text -> Parser [Text]
parseColourGen = sequence . intersperse (mempty <$ many1 legalSep) . 
                   fmap string . words

parseColour :: [(Text, Colour)] -> Parser Colour
parseColour = foldl1 (<|>) . fmap (\(text, colour) ->
  colour <$ parseColourGen text)

legalSep :: Parser Text
legalSep = singleton <$> satisfy (inClass "\n\r- ")
```

You can then feed your `wordList` to the parser; however, it needs to be an association list:

```
wordList :: [(Text, Colour)]
wordList = [("light blue", LightBlue), ("dark blue", DarkBlue), ("vibrant red", VibrantRed)]
```

This way, you can configure all of your colours and their corresponding colour names in one place, and you can then run the parser like so:

```
> parse (parseColour wordList) $ pack "vibrant-red"
Done "" VibrantRed
```

**EDIT**

After the edit in your question, I think I understand what you want a little bit better. FWIW, I would still prefer the solution above, but here is how to fix your last block of code:

1. As the compiler should tell you, patterns `(w:ws)` and `[w]` overlap, so if you want the runtime to catch the single-element pattern, you have to place it on top.
2. `a >> b` means "run action `a`, discard its result, then run action `b` and use that result". Which is why your parser (with the fix above) will output `Done "" "blue"`. A simple way to fix this is to use `do` notation to bind the result of all three computations, and return their concatenation.

Here is what your code now looks like:

```
wordListParser :: [Text] -> Parser Text
wordListParser [w] = string w
wordListParser (w:ws) = do
  a <- string w
  b <- satisfy (inClass " -")
  c <- wordListParser ws
  return (a `append` (singleton b) `append` c) -- singleton :: Char -> Text
wordListParser [] = empty
```

One last thing: your current implementation will not parse Windows line breaks (`\n\r`). I don't know if you dropped `\n` and `\r` from your separator characters, but if you haven't and Windows files are a possibility for you, it's something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not familiar with attoparsec, but you could possibly use a recursive solution:

```hs
wordListParser :: [T.Text] -> Parser
wordListParser [] = empty
wordListParser [w] = text w
wordListParser (w:ws) = text w >> inClass "\n\r- " >> wordListParser ws
```

Comment: Any idea where to find the empty parser? I've tried `Parser T.empty` and `T.empty` but not getting much closer.

Comment: @Jonathan [Hoogle's got you.](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=empty) The very first result is the right one.

Comment: This just produces a partial parse, and doesn't complete.

Comment: @Jonathan What do you mean by ‘it produces a partial parse’? Can you give an example where it doesn’t work?

Comment: I've just added an example to my question, showing where it returns `Partial _`.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan! I see the problem now: the `[w]` case is never reached, since I put the cases in the wrong order. I’ll edit my post now.